# Template helper to dynamically set div id, Meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I have this template event:

```
'click .edit_user_button': function(ev){
        ev.preventDefault();

        var id = this._id;

        var children = $("'#" + id + "'");

        console.log(children);

        children.css('display', 'inline-block');
    }
```

That I want to target this input:

`<input class='user_input form-control edit_fields' id='username_field {{_id}}' type="text" name='username' placeholder="username">`

but I can't get it to work.  The template has scope, and `this._id` matches {{_id}} in the template.

Comment: Your code works for me if you get rid of the single quotes in your declaration of the children variable: change $("'#" + id + "'");  Change to $("#" + id);

Answer (score 0):

Is `children` supposed to be the variable that targets the `input` ?

This is just elementary jQuery.

```
var input = $('input[username]').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the meteor way to do manual DOM manipulation. If you want a class on an element to be dynamic, just write a helper function to return that class from a reactive variable (collection, session or reactiveVar). For example, for an input to be disabled reactively, do this:

```
<input id="chopoffthehead" disabled={{isDisabled}}/>
```

helper function:

```
isDisabled: function() {
  return  Session.get('isCreatureHydra');
}
```

This way, whenever the session variable isCreatureHydra is set to true, the input will be disabled.